# Windows 10 File Explorer | bad characters in file names in search results

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10, search, hebrew

I using Win10 (upgraded from Win7 a few weeks ago) in English, and Hebrew as added supported language.

Basically everything is fine with Hebrew files names, folder names and so on, except for one thing - when I'm searching for a file in Hebrew...

What I search for a file in the embedded search feature of the File Explorer with Hebrew characters, I do get results (and the right ones), but the displayed result files appear with bad characters in the file names, where they should appear in Hebrew letters. Normally, all these files appear correctly as they should in their folders and so on.

Btw, the folder names in which these files are found appear correctly in Hebrew letters in the same results...

[image]

These results are correct in correspondance with the search text itself, but do not appear in Hebrew letters, but these strange ones. The folder names of these results do appear in Hebrew.

I'm trying to understand why is it happening like that and how I can fix it.

Comment: Did it work correctly in Windows 7?

Comment: yes, absolutely

Comment: Sound like a bug then in WIndows 10. start > feedback and report it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was asked a pretty while ago, but as I found this when I was looking for a solution, now that I've managed to fix it I'll write it down here for the next person...

This problem occurs when the fonts that the UI uses are somehow missing or damaged. This can happen by uninstalling a program which mistakenly think that it needs to uninstall a certain font with it, or sometimes when installing a whole lot of fonts at a time and Windows asks you if you want to replace the fonts that are already installed and you press Yes, which means that the font is overwritten with the font you have which mustn't be the correct latest version.

What is needed to be done is got a hold on all the default fonts that come with your version of Windows and install them all. It is possible to take them from the C:\Windows\Fonts folder of a fresh Windows installation or even extract them from the Windows ISO. But if you want I've uploaded all the default Windows 10 fonts here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao8EzDmtlA0JhW8fWLoAS1t27cxC

What you should do is:

1. Download the ZIP file
2. Extract it to a folder
3. Copy all its contents to C:\Windows\Fonts folder of your computer
4. If Windows says for some fonts that they're already installed and asks if you want to replace them, click yes to have them replaced with the fresh good font
5. If it doesn't help right away restart the PC and see if it takes
   effect

Hope this helps anyone who experiences this very annoying problem!

Comment: This is indeed a quite older question (just remembered I posted it), so since then some update to Windows along the way fixed this issue also. However, if someone still encounters this situation, adding these fonts to Windows will take care of it also. That's why I chose this answer as the solution here. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, it was indeed a corrupted font. I can search again :)
You deserve more then a +1 for this.